# how can I put an item with checked = true depending on the info in the DB?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js, lodash

I have a list of items with the option to checked or unchecked them. I am doing a post request in order to save the unchecked items, and that post request works great, but I am having an issue with the get request, the front-end retrieves fine the info from the back-end, but I have this function which is putting on `checked = true` the items without taking care of the unchecked items saved already

```
      if (sports.length) {
         $scope.sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
         sport.checked = true;
          return sport;
         });
      };
```

so, if the user refreshes the page, all items get back to `checked = true` due to the function above. So how can I do to persist the items with checked or unchecked ? what do I have to change in that function in order to persist that data ?

this is my code regarding the get request of that data

I am using `lodash`, just in case...

**front-end**

**controller.js**

**please read the note in this code**

```
.controller('SportsController', function($scope, SportsFactory, AuthFactory) {

$scope.sports = [];

SportsFactory.getSportChecked(customer).then(function(sportChecked) {
            _.each(sports, function(sport) {
              var sportIds = _.pluck(sports, 'id'),
                  intersectedSports = _.intersection(sportIds, sportChecked),
                  checkedSportObjects = _.filter(sport, function(sportObj) {
                    return _.includes(intersectedSports, sportObj);
                  });
              _.each(checkedSportObjects, function(sport) {
                $scope.sports.push(sport);
              });
            });
          }

//this is the function putting checked = true with out taking care
//of what the back-end returns

 if (sports.length) {
   $scope.sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
     sport.checked = true;
     return sport;
    });
 }

 $scope.toggleSportSelection = function(sport) {
  var params = {};
  params.user = $scope.customer.customer;
  params.sport = sport.id;
  sport.checked = !sport.checked;
  SportsFactory.setSportChecked(params);
 };

});
```

**service.js**

```
.factory('SportsFactory', function($http, $q, AuthFactory,
                                   LocalForageFactory, CONSTANT_VARS) {

 return {

      getSportChecked: function(customer) {
        var defer = $q.defer(),
            user,
            rejection = function(err) {
              console.log(err);
              defer.reject(err);
            };
        LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED)
          .then(function(sportChecked) {
            user = customer.customer;
            if (!_.isNull(sportChecked)) {
              defer.resolve(sportChecked);
            }else {
              $http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/sports/getChecked/' + user)
              .success(function(sportChecked) {
                LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED, sportChecked);
                defer.resolve(sportChecked);
              })
              .error(rejection);
            }
          }, rejection);
        return defer.promise;
      }
 }
});
```

**BACK-END - node.js/sails.js**

**SetSportsController**

```
module.exports = {

  retrieveSetCheck: function(req, res) {
    if (req.params) {
 SportSelectionService.getSportChecked(req.params).then(function(sportChecked) {
        res.json(200, sportChecked);
      }, function(err) {
        res.json(400, err);
      });
    }else {
      res.json(400, {error: 'Error retrieving Sports'});
    }
  }
}
```

**SportSelectionService**

```
module.exports = {
 getSportChecked: function(params) {
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
      console.time('sportChecked_findOne');
      SportSelection.find({
        user: params.user
      }).exec(function(err, sportChecked) {
        console.timeEnd('sportChecked_findOne');
        if (err) {
          reject(new Error('Error finding sportChecked'));
          console.error(err);
        }else {
          if (sportChecked) {
            fullfill(sportChecked);
          }else {
            console.time('sportChecked_create');
            SportSelection.create({
              sport: [],
              user: params.user
            }).exec(function(err, created) {
              console.timeEnd('sportChecked_create');
              console.log(err);
              console.log(created);
              if (err) {
                reject(new Error('Error on sportChecked'));
              }else {
                fullfill(created);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand that `sportChecked` represents a model of some sort, but at what point are you looking at the model and determining whether it is checked?

Comment: It seems like a function called `getSportChecked` should only return `checked` sports, so `if (sportChecked && sportChecked.checked === true) ...`

Comment: @AustinMullins I am determining that in a post I did, you wan to see the code for the post request ?

Comment: @AustinMullins and where do I put that code you said? can you give me a little example with code ? please

Comment: In the `getSportChecked` method of the `SportSelectionService`. Right now, it looks up a user, and if found, says `if (sportChecked) fullfill(sportChecked)`. But you probably don't want to return every sport, just the checked ones right?

Comment: @AustinMullins yes, that is correct, only the checked ones

Comment: @AustinMullins actually the ones I am saving are the unchecked ones, because all the sports are set up to true at the beginning, so once you change the statement to checked = false, those are the ones saved so far. And I have those sports saved properly right now, but thanks to the function ```if(sport.length){...}``` that I post above, the sports unchecked comes to true after I refresh the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72787/discussion-between-austin-mullins-and-nietzscheprogrammer).

Comment: @AustinMullins look at the chat